# chapter headings which command cuases this?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters

I would like to know which command causes this frame:

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to mix three different fonts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
%\usepackage[bf]{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath,mathtools}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\ChTitleVar{\Huge\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Your Title }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your suggestion  MWE, can somethign be deletet

Comment: You want  me to delete useless packages, right?

Comment: Right, everything useless.